# How to display different objects in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

A table in my database has stored pictures, documents, dll halyards and so on. How do I implement the mapping of all this for a user?
I bind these data to a data table, and want to have hyperlinks in each cell, which when clicked, invokes/opens the corresponding item from the database.

```
OracleCommand oracleCom = new OracleCommand();
oracleCom.Connection = oraConnect;
oracleCom.CommandText = "Select * From " + Session["tableNameIns"];
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new Oraenter code herecleDataAdapter();
DataTable tableD = new DataTable();
tableD.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
adapter.SelectCommand = oracleCom;
adapter.Fill(tableD);
changeTableAtributs(tableD);
tableResults.DataSource = tableD.AsDataView();
tableResults.DataBind();
```

In DB next atributes: i_id(number), i_objecttype_id(number), s_code(nvarchar), s_name(nvarchar), m_content(blob), m_description(nvarchar)
[image: dbview]

On client I see next: i_id(number), i_objecttype_id(number), s_code(nvarchar), s_name(nvarchar), m_description(nvarchar).
Without atribute m_content.
[image: clienview]

Comment: Please explain your scenario in brief so that everyone can understand your question. And if possible then explain with simple example. The more you provide information, The better you get solution.

Comment: Please explain more with example..

Comment: What about using an Interface and BindingSource?

Comment: Have you tried something like this?  labelname.Text = "<a href=#>text</a>";

Comment: Your command text looks ripe for the SQL injection picking. You should probably paramterize that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your question is "incomplete". So if the blob is a picture you want the picture to be displayed? What should happen if the blob is a dll?

In your database the M_CONTENT field is a blob so if you databind that to a GridView the GridView has no way of knowing what is in that field.

If you want an image displayed to show the type of the file in the blob then you need to know the type. Either you store the type in the database (Optimal) or you parse the blob at runtime and figure out the file type.

It seems to me that you already have the type (I_OBJECTTYPE_ID). If that is the case then you can define a column under asp:GridView/Columns

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File type">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="mediaImage"
            ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("type") as string) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your case the type column is called I_OBJECTTYPE_ID. The GetImageUrl is a function in the codebehind:

```
switch (type)
{
    case "video":
        return "~//Images//video.png";
    case "audio":
        return "~//Images//audio.png";
}
return ""; // Something is wrong
```

And using this technique you can make Hyperlinks and other stuff under the ItemTemplate markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those values in the RowDataBound event of the GridView and create your links/hyperlinks and assign them to the rows

```
    protected void tableResults_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            if (row != null)
            {
                Label lbImagePath = e.Row.FindControl("lbImagePath") as Label;
                lbImagePath.Text = row["ImagePathColumn"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

In your case change that Label to a HyperLink control and sets it's URL to the column value

Comment: I meant to display different objects. Not links.

Comment: What do you mean by different objects?

Comment: Yeah, you say in your original question that you want to have hyperlinks in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user download the file instead of showing (because dll can be shown on browser) then do as following:

1. create a new page say `downloadfile.aspx`;
2. In `datarowbound` event parse the values needed to download the file
   like filetype, filename, etc; say you have saved `abc.pdf` as blob then the hyperlink url should be `downloadfile.aspx?fname=abc.pdf&type=application&pkey=uniqueidentification`;
3. In `downloadfile.aspx` load event get the blob as `byte[]` based upon `uniqueidentification` (i.e primary key). Convert it into stream and give then in response like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592455/converting-blob-back-to-original-file-type-and-making-it-available-for-download).

Answer (score 0):

To accomplished this, you must use ***TemplateField***. You will insert controls to each cell and bind data using ***Eval*** function. For more information, please refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

make the grid button to each row and use select or delete or update button .

e.selectedindex.

u can always change the header or hide the header.

u can also use events like selectedindexchanged, so once u selected u get the selected index id so using that can invoke method

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, in **TemplateField** you have **EditTemplateField** and **ItemTemplateField**, in ItemTemplateField put your column names Ex: Age: and in the Text Bind("Age") and in ItemTemplate copy everythinh from EditTemplate and paste it their, dont exactly copy my code this is example, i have made my code display in a table. So now you can edit everything like HTML just put the links as href thats it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewFemale" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceFemale" Width="158px">
    <Columns>
         <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" NullImageUrl="images/INA.jpg" ShowHeader="False"></asp:ImageField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                             <b> Age:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Name:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Education:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Education") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Current Status:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrentStatus") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Height:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Height") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Complexion:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Complexion") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Caste:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Caste") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Group:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Group") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table id="GridTable">
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                             <b> Age:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Name:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Education:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Education") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Current Status:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CurrentStatus") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Height:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Height") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Complexion:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Complexion") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Caste:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Caste") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                            <b> Group:</b> <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Group") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```