# how to convert Hibernate Blob back to original File

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to store Zipped files in the database, I have created the Blob file with `Hibernate.createBlob(input stream)`

Now i want to reverse the process and convert the Blob to File so i can open it with Zip4j
How exactly am i supposed to do that? 
i tried to do this but i always get an exception

> ```
>   File file = new File("origfile.zip");
>     try {
>         InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream(); <- exception
>         FileOutputStream opt = new FileOutputStream(file);
>         int read = 0;
>         byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
>         while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
>             opt.write(bytes, 0, read);
>         }
> ```

and the exception is:

> ```
> 2013-07-03 18:38:35,482 [DEBUG] [HibernateTransactionManager,doBegin(),569] - Exposing 
> Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@69875a82]
> java.sql.SQLException: could not reset reader
> at org.hibernate.lob.BlobImpl.getBinaryStream(BlobImpl.java:106)
> at org.hibernate.lob.SerializableBlob.getBinaryStream(SerializableBlob.java:62)
> at com.gleeb.backbonetemplates.services.LivePreviewService.prepareDesignForLivePreview(LivePreviewService.java:35)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.
The way i used to convert the blob to file is OK. the exception happens because of hibernate self issues you might call it.

To prevent the exception from happening i needed to do a refresh() after the save.

```
session.refresh(blog);
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this example solution in c# the code should be relatively similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592455/converting-blob-back-to-original-file-type-and-making-it-available-for-download)

I know it's not and ideal answer but it's a good starting point.

Comment: The concept is understood very well, this is a java/Hibernate technical problem. Thank you though