# How to decode MySql blob from backup file?

Tags: c#, mysql

I got a MySql backup file containing a column like:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`profilepicture` blob,
)
```

The content of this row profilepicture is encoded in the backup file to some kind of dump, starting (in a text editor) like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tbox_account_transaction` VALUES (8,'?\?\?0JFIF\0\0\0\0\0\0[...]');
```

How can I decode this from the .sql backup file in c#? It is not Base64, but I do not recognize what else it might be. I don't want to restore the backup.sql file to MySql but instead decode the blob from the backup file.

Comment: So what happens if you rename the file to `something.jpg`, does it open?

Comment: Are you sure it's encoded Sam? Blob data usually appears like that (e.g. if the database were running and you did a `SELECT profilepicture FROM person` it'd return something like that). If it's unencoded you can just convert the value directly into a file - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592455/converting-blob-back-to-original-file-type-and-making-it-available-for-download/8592869

Comment: The file contains `CREATE TABLE`s and more, I added some info for clarifcation. The database is not running, I just got a backup file and want to decode the blob from the backup.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes you are seeing are almost certainly the initial bytes of a JPEG image. The readable string "JFIF" starting at the fifth byte is the clue (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format).

Many of the other binary bytes are null or else non-printable characters. All the weird `\?` or `\0` sequences are the client's best effort at representing these bytes on your text display.

The easiest way to access this data is to restore the dump file to a MySQL instance (even a local one running on a laptop), and then use SQL in your C# code to access the binary contents of the `profilepicture` blob.

Either save the data from one blob to a `.jpg` file as @Tommaso Belluzzo suggests, or else just display it directly, if you can. I'm not a C# programmer, but it seems there's a `Bitmap` class for this (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tda2c3c(v=vs.85).aspx).

It's outside the scope of a Stack Overflow answer to give a tutorial on how to write SQL in a C# application. There are plenty of resources available for that.

Comment: I have no MySql Server available where I need to read this file, so I somehow want to decode the information from the backup.sql file - I just need information how it is encoded in the backup.sql file. For example the `'` is encoded as `\'`... I know how to create a file from a stream and how to create a bitmap class, but I need to decode the information first.

Comment: I assume it's not encoded at all, it's just binary bytes embedded in the backup file among human-readable bytes. So you should be able to truncate the file before and after the blob data, and that'll be a JPEG.

Comment: Or else it's encoded with MySQL string-literal escapes, which you can read about here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: `'` is obviously encoded to `\'`, so the string-literal-encoding looks promising, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a `jpg` file header. Try the following (`blob` is a `String` typed variable containing the `profilepicture`):

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
    image.Save("C:\\Test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I did not downvote—I upvoted this answer, because you're likely right that the blob data is binary bytes of a JPEG image. But I would comment that it's kind of missing the steps that the OP will need to get the data from the SQL dump file into your `buffer` in this code example.

Comment: I edited my question for clarification: The database is not running, I only got a backup file and want to decode the blob from the backup.sql